# What's the best way to squash & stretch an entire rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

Is there a good way to do this? I've tried scaling the rig on Z, and parenting the rig to an empty and scaling that. Both of those produce some pretty weird results:

[image: Scaling a rig of a frog on a skateboard]

Comment: Would it work putting it in a lattice? I've just gave that a go to see and although the bones don't follow the stretched mesh, they still seem to work

Comment: @wilks Deforming it with a lattice behaves the same way, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm afraid you may just have to animate it to have effect you are looking for